# how to link from table view cell to table view controller

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my app, I have a View Controller that contains a static Table View Cell with 8 cells. Each cell is pushed to a respective View Controller.

One of these cells must link to a Table View Controller which will contain a dynamically-controlled Table View Cell. I am getting a Bad Access Error and can't figure out why.

Comment: please add snippets with problem code for us to see where bug could be. Bad access means that you have some memory management problems

Comment: In this case I suggest you to use Master-Detail view controller (UISplitViewController). Would please post code and console output to find out the issue?